# Debezium - Start MySQL binlog Reading from a specific binlog position or GTID

Tags: mysql, debezium

I have a MySQL server with more than 2TB of data, I want to sync it with another MySQL server. I want to skip the snapshot and instead I took a dump and restore. Now I want to steam only after a specific binlog file name and position or GTID.

I didn't get any options for this from the Debezium docs.

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why would you need Debezium to replicate changes from one MySQL Server to another MySQL Server? Just use MySQL replication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/change-master-to.html

Comment: Its a different use case, im working on some migration from VM to CloudSQL, due to some issues its not possible to fix that. GCP supports confirms its a bug and they'll fix it. So I wanted to try something like this

Comment: You could also use [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to create periodic incremental dump files, and import them. Sort of like your dump and restore, but only from a certain position in the binary log.